# Threads in Java, states? Also what is the right way to use them?

Tags: java, multithreading, computer-science

I'm up for my exame presentation the day after tomorrow, so i need to get some straight before it which i hope you guys can help me with.

First i do know that there are 4 states of Threads (i.e Running, Ready, Blocked, Terminated), however i'm not quite sure how it works in Java. In my code i use the thread.sleep(3000) to do some waiting in the program, does this make the thread Blocked or Ready?

Also it have come to my attention that i might not have used the threads the right way, let me show you some code

```
public class BattleHandler implements Runnable {

private Player player;
private Monster enemyMonster;
private Dungeon dungeon;
private JTextArea log;
private GameScreen gScreen;


public void run() {
    try {
        runBattle();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e);}
}

public BattleHandler(Player AttackingPlayer, JTextArea log, GameScreen gScreen) {
    this.player = AttackingPlayer;
    this.log = log;
    this.gScreen = gScreen;
}

public void setDungeon(Dungeon dungeon) {
    this.dungeon = dungeon;
}

public Dungeon getDungeon() {
    return dungeon;
}

public Monster getEnemyMonster() {
    return enemyMonster;
}

public void setMonster() {

    // First check if dungeon have been init, if not we can't generate the mob
    if(dungeon != null) {

        enemyMonster = new Monster();
        // Generate monster stats
        enemyMonster.generateStats(dungeon);

    }else {
        System.out.println("Dungeon was not initialized");
    }

}
   public void runBattle() throws InterruptedException {

    // Start battle, and run until a contester is dead.

    while(player.getHealth() > 0 && enemyMonster.getHealth() > 0) {

        int playerStrikeDmg = player.strike();

        if(enemyMonster.blockDefend()) {
            log.setText( log.getText() + "\n" + player.getName() +" tried to strike " + enemyMonster.getName()+ ", but " + enemyMonster.getName() + " Blocked.");
        }else if(enemyMonster.dodgeDefend()) {
            log.setText( log.getText() + "\n" + player.getName() +" tried to strike " + enemyMonster.getName()+ ", but " + enemyMonster.getName() + " Blocked.");
        }else {
            enemyMonster.defend(playerStrikeDmg);
            log.setText( log.getText() + "\n" + player.getName() +" strikes " + enemyMonster.getName()+ " for: " + playerStrikeDmg + " left: "+ enemyMonster.getHealth());
        }



        if(enemyMonster.getHealth() < 1) break;

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        // Monster Turn

        int monsterDmg = enemyMonster.strike();


        if(player.blockDefend()) {
            log.setText( log.getText() + "\n" + enemyMonster.getName() +" tried to strike " + player.getName()+ ", but " + player.getName()+ " Blocked.");
        }else if(player.dodgeDefend()) {
            log.setText( log.getText() + "\n" + enemyMonster.getName() +" tried to strike " + player.getName()+ ", but " + player.getName()+ " Dodged.");
        }else {
            player.defend(monsterDmg);
            log.setText( log.getText() + "\n" + enemyMonster.getName() +" strikes " + player.getName()+ " for: " + monsterDmg + " left: "+ player.getHealth());
        }
        gScreen.updateBot();
        Thread.sleep(3000);

    }
```

When i coded this i thought it was cool, but i have seen some make a class just for controlling the Thread itself. I have just made the class who uses the Sleep runable(Which is not shown in the code, but its a big class).

Would be good to get this straight, so i can point i out before they ask me about it, you know take away there ammunition. :D

Hope you guys can help me :).

Thx

Comment: Where's the implementation of the `runBattle()` method? And what exactly is your question? Right now it's not really clear what kind of answer you expect. From such a small piece of code it's not possible to tell if you use threads the "correct" way or not.

Comment: I've add the runbattle, my apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads have more than 4 [states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html). Also, I recommend reading [Lesson: Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) for more information regarding threads.

Note that if you're looking to execute a task at a set interval, I highly recommend using the [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) framework.

Comment: Thx mre, great link! The program is not open for change, i just need to be prepared for mistakes i may or may not have made.

Answer (score 1):

Blocked - it will not run at all until timeout.  Ready is 'runnable now but there is no processor available to run it - will run as soon as a processor becomes available'.

Comment: what you say about "Ready" can be understood the wrong way. It does not mean that the process will try to "get" a free processor. such a thing is not possible. It means that the OS-Scheduler is currently calculating on another process. once it decides to switch to another process, it may pick, depending on the OS-Strategy one of the "Ready" threads in the OS-Queue. also "blocked" does not mean that it will timeout. it means that another operation blocks this threads execution. once this ends, it may very well return and work

Comment: Given the OP's set of four thread states, 'blocked' is nearest:)  Freeing up a processor, (eg. to preempt a lower priority thread in order to run a high-priority thread that has just become ready), is certainly possible at OS level.

Answer (score 0):

As all the other guys state, there are more than those, here's a simple listing:

1. Running - Guess what, it's running
2. Waiting - It waits for another thread to complete its calculation (that's the wait() method in Java). Basically such a thread can also be run by the scheduler, like the "ready" state threads.
3. Ready - Means that the Thread is ready for execution, once the OS-Scheduler turns to this Thread, it will execute it
4. Blocked - Means that there is another operation, blocking this threads execution, such as IO.
5. Terminated - Guess what, it's done and will be removed by the OS-Scheduler.

For a complete listing, look at the famous Wikipedia ;)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state